# How to enable theme on profile installation

Tags: 6, theming, distributions

I am creating a drupal 6 installation profile and I want to enable a specific theme on installation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your profile_name.info, add a new line with `theme = mytheme`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Install Profile API](http://drupal.org/project/install_profile_api)'s [install_enable_theme()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!install_profile_api!core!system.inc/function/install_enable_theme/6) function.